# Angular 10 - cannot force error using HttpClient delete()

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, httpclient

so I'm following an Angular tutorial right now and in the error-handling-chapter I'm currently stuck because I cannot force an error to appear when feeding a HttpClient.delete()-request with wrong data.

I've cut that part out but I'm getting my data (posts) from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.

I've tried to feed the delete-function with bad ids in multiple places.
I've used ids that should be out of border and 1 for example which should be deleted after clicking the "delete"-Button twice but nothing forced an error.

What it's doing instead is it's working perfectly fine meaning it's emptying my posts-list and it's doing so by deleting exactly the posts that I clicked on.

I've tried simplifying it by cutting out the error-services and doing everything in the posts-component but it didn't help.

posts.component.ts

```
import { BadInputError } from './../common/bad-input';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { PostService } from './../services/post.service';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppError } from '../common/app-error';

@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
  posts: any[];
  constructor(private service: PostService) { }

  // ...

  deletePost(post) {
    this.service.deletePost(post.id).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
        this.posts.splice(index, 1);
      }, 
      (error: AppError) => {
        if (error instanceof NotFoundError)
          alert('This post has already been deleted.');
        else {
          alert('An unexpected error occured.');
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
}
```

posts.component.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li 
        *ngFor="let post of posts"
        class="list-group-item">
        <button 
            (click)="deletePost(post)"
            class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            Delete
        </button>
        {{ post.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

post.service.ts

```
export class PostService {
  private url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // ...

  deletePost(id) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (error.status === 404)
            // throw Observable.throw(new NotFoundError);
            throw throwError(error);
            //return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError);
          else
            return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
        })
      );
  }
}
```

app-error.ts

```
export class AppError {
    constructor(public originalError?: any) {}
}
```

not-found-error.ts

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';

export class NotFoundError extends AppError {}
```

bad-input.ts

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';

export class BadInputError extends AppError {}
```

I would be very thankful for someone explaining me, what I'm doing wrong and how I can force errors to test my application.

Kind regards

Comment: What's your problem exactly? what did you get wrong? the Http errors they depends on tot the server-side response

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to check whether the error messages work but I'm unable to force them.
In the tutorial that I'm following, simply wrong id that don't exist in the list have been given to the delete-function and the error popped up but in my code it is working correctly even with the wrong ids.

Comment: Why you didn't make a simple console.log to log your error message

Comment: That would have proven that the error messages work but I was also hoping for an explanation on why the way I was trying did not work. Also I wanted to see whether the pop ups work. My version below does not answer my question but it at least shows the pop ups.

Answer (score 0):

So it's not quite the solution/answer for my problem/question but at least I now know how to test my error-handling.

I can just throw an error inside of the error-handling-function before it's body is being executed:

```
delete(id) {
  return throwError(new NotFoundError);

  return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```